# Does the series diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ diverges and each $a_k>0$. Is it true that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k}$ also diverges?

Comment: I am actually trying to find a series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ that diverges, but $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}b_k/a_k = 0$. I think that if $b_k=a_k/k$ then it should work, but I am unsure about the divergence of  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty b_k$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to try the case of $a_k=\frac1k$

Comment: Thank you for the response. If $a_k=\frac{1}{k}$ then by the integral test it definitely diverges. Though this is a specific case.

Comment: @Burgundy I assumed that you'd already know the harmonic series to be divergent - it is about the first example of a divergent series one encounters, years before the words "integral test" even make sense. Likewise, $\sum \frac1{n^2}$ is usually among the first series one is presented.